# Select after insert doesn't return the inserted row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, codeigniter-3

**Background information:** I work on an application (professional, not personal) who manage files. The UI is web based and the low-level file managing functions are Java based.

Each file and directory is referred to as a 'node' in this app and has a row in a table who store its inode, name, parent id, etc...

**The problem:** When we do an action like adding a node or renaming it for example, a java function is called to update the database in relation to the real file system.

I have the problem only when we copy a node (everything works perfectly when we add, rename, delete, ... a node even if the same exact java function is called as for the copy) ==> the file is copied, then the java function is called (in this case it does an SQL insert of the new file infos) and finally I do a select in PHP to get the node id of the copied file.

Just after the insert I can see the row in PhpMyAdmin but the select in PHP doesn't return it.

**What I've tried:** It's not the timing (I've put a 20 seconds sleep to test and to have the time to see the row in PMA) and all caches are disabled in CodeIgniter (and I've put various dumps in the CodeIgniter code to confirm). I also tried with the PDO driver of CodeIgniter and the result is exactly the same. And I've tried to delete some of the conditions in the where clause (and the where clause altogether too) and again, same result.

The only thing that works is to open a new connection to the DB and redo the query as in the code below:

```
public function getIdForNode($name, $parentId) {
    $id = 0;
    $name = self::cleanName($name);
    $parentId = intval($parentId);
    if (empty($name)) {
        Log::error("\$name can't be empty.");
    } else if ($parentId < 0) {
        Log::error("\$parentId can't be < 0.");
    } else {
        $db = AppDatabase::getInstance();
        $sql = "SELECT node_ID
                FROM nodes
                WHERE inode_id > 0
                    AND parentNode_ID = ?
                    AND record_label = BINARY ?
                    AND record_deleted IS NULL";
        $result = $db->query($sql, [$parentId, $name])->row_array();
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if (empty($result)) {
            $db2 = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
            $result2 = $db2->query("
                SELECT node_ID
                FROM nodes
                WHERE inode_id > 0
                    AND parentNode_ID = ".$parentId."
                    AND record_label = BINARY '".$db2->escape_string($name)."'
                    AND record_deleted IS NULL
            ");
            $result = $result2->fetch_assoc();
            $result2->free();
            $db2->close();
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $id = (!empty($result) && !empty($result['node_ID'])) ? intval($result['node_ID']) : 0;
    }
    return $id;
}
```

MySQL 5.5
PHP 5.5
CodeIgniter 3

Please let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: Make sure $db is the instance of database. (var_dump to check instance values . run any simple select query if you not getting any results then there is error in db instance .  or if you are in model / controller in codeigniter , then i guess one will be using global db object $this->db->->query('params')

Comment: I'm sure it's the correct DB object because I've dumped it, I also put dumps in the DB driver itself and everything is ok; I do get results if I remove the where condition (and yes the condition is correct, if I execute the same query in PMA I get the row).

Comment: You're failing to check for errors in certain places, particularly the call to ``$db2->query()``. Without checking for errors, you'll never know when you have one.

Comment: [Here are some examples for checking errors](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php) (connect and query)

Comment: Why are you using two different connections $db and $db2? I assume, that the info from $db isn't updated, when you insert over $db2.

Comment: I don't need to check this error, all the parameters are already checked and the query is correct. BTW the problem has nothing to do with that, I know the query is correctly executed and that there is no error.

@Myonara I already explained why I do the same query twice: the first one doesn't return the row so I added the second one as a temporary fix. It's the same DB, the same user, same driver, same query, same parameters.

Answer (score 0):

1) Mysqli has a method used to get the last insert id. This would allow you to simply use that value without requiring a select.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

2) Turn on mysql debugging and watch it run once. You may find your solution.

3) I don't see an INSERT at all, so the SELECT statement following an insert ... isn't something I can troubleshoot (since it only happens on a certain type of insert).

In the end, you'll need to see why there is a difference between this SELECT and another SELECT and you've already related it to the previous INSERT statement. But you didn't provide the INSERT statement nor show a difference in how this select relates to that insert compared to other inserts.

So you'll want to turn on mysql debugging and get each of the statements as they run to see if you can duplicate the problem outside your java/php code. Perhaps you just have a chase situation where the java code executes out of order (happens a lot with AJAX) or hasn't technically completed the insert before the select executes. Been there. ;)